Swift accessor macro with dynamic value
I want to write a macro GetSetMacro which is taking in the value of the stored property of the type and generate the accessors for another property based on it.
// Definition
@attached(accessor)
public macro GetSetMacro<Value>(_ : Value)  = #externalMacro(module: "MyMacroModule", type: "GetSetMacro")

// Implementation
public struct GetSetMacro: AccessorMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: SwiftSyntax.AttributeSyntax, providingAccessorsOf declaration: some SwiftSyntax.DeclSyntaxProtocol, in context: some SwiftSyntaxMacros.MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [SwiftSyntax.AccessorDeclSyntax] {
        guard
             case let .argumentList(arguments) = node.arguments,
             let argument = arguments.first
           else { return [] }
       
        return [
            """
              get {
                // How to access the member value of the type in here?
                ???
              }
              """,
              """
              set {
                ??? = newValue
              }
            """
        ]
    }
}

Example usage
var value = 1

@GetSetMacro(\.value)
var newIntValue: Int

// expansion
var newIntValue {
 get {
   value
 } set {
    value = newValue
 }
}


Using a string literal to represent a member isn't a good design, is it? It is easy to make typos and renaming things become harder. How about taking a KeyPath instead? Then your problem becomes very trivial.

okay I updated can you please comment how to access the value with keypath in the expansion?

In the macro declaration, take a WritableKeyPath:
@attached(accessor, names: named(get), named(set))
public macro GetSet<Root, Value>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<Root, Value>) = #externalMacro(...)

The implementation just uses the [keyPath: ...] subscript to get and set the desired key path.
enum GetSetMacro: AccessorMacro {
    static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, providingAccessorsOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [AccessorDeclSyntax] {
        guard let keyPath = node.arguments?.as(LabeledExprListSyntax.self)?.first?.expression else {
            return []
        }
        return [
            """
            get { self[keyPath: \(keyPath)] }
            """,
            """
            set { self[keyPath: \(keyPath)] = newValue }
            """
        ]
    }
}

Example usage:
class Foo {
    var value = 1
    
    @GetSet(\Foo.value)
    var newIntValue: Int
}

Notes:

Type checking is performed after macro expansion. That is, you cannot check that the key path's root type matches the type of the enclosing class/struct, or that the type of the property matches the type of the key path.
You have to write a full key path like \Foo.value. The compiler cannot infer the root type.


Good answer. I am almost there when writing unit test and this is still expanded in unit test but in actual usage it gives the type error as expected. Is that because ype checking is performed after macro expansion?
"""
            class Foo {
                var value = ""
                @GetSet(\\Foo.value)
                var newIntValue: Int
            }
"""


@hariszaman yes, exactly. I’m not sure how you can test for errors like that in a test, though.

I created a basic solution to your problem; both with the String approach as well as with the KeyPath approach.
extension String: Error {}

public struct GetSetMacro: AccessorMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, providingAccessorsOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [AccessorDeclSyntax] {
        guard let arguments = node.arguments,
              let expression = arguments.as(LabeledExprListSyntax.self)?.first?.expression else {
            throw "Incorrect argument"
        }

        if let string = expression.as(StringLiteralExprSyntax.self) {
            return [
                "get { \(raw: string.segments) }",
                "set { \(raw: string.segments) = newValue }",
            ]
        } else if let keyPath = expression.as(KeyPathExprSyntax.self) {
            return [
                "get { self[keyPath: \(raw: keyPath.description)] }",
                "set { self[keyPath: \(raw: keyPath.description)] = newValue }"
            ]
        } else {
            throw "Unsupported argument"
        }
    }
}

So in order to extract the variable passed into your macro, you'd have to traverse the node.arguments in some way. If you use the Xcode template to create your macro, you can breakpoint inside your macro code and use lldb to see how you can extract the data you'd like to have.
